# Python error expected an indented block

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Hi again And sorry for my Mistake in Describe my problem.
this my little function so i saved in a file name nester.py

def print_lol(the_list):

```
  for each_item in the_list:    
    if isinstance(each_item,list):
        print_lol(each_item)
    else:
        print(each_item)
```

and when i want to use it and press F5. I faced with above error in Python 3.4.3 Shell.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Hello , when i press F5 to Run Module I saw above error means:"expected an identical block".

Comment: I'd imagine it says *"expected an **indented** block"*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to 1) actually ask a question, 2) include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are receiving, and 3) show your program's inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs (if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your code. All blocks should be indented by 4 spaces.